# Function to find factors of a number, optionally including 1 and the number itself

Tags: python, functional-programming, factors

I have a function for finding factors of a number in Python

```
def factors(n, one=True, itself=False):
    def factors_functional():
        # factors below sqrt(n)
        a = filter(lambda x: n % x == 0,
                   xrange(2, int(n**0.5)+1))
        result = a + map(lambda x: n / x, reversed(a))
        return result
```

`factors(28)` gives `[2, 4, 7, 14]`. Now i want this function to also include 1 in the beginning of a list, if `one` is true, and 28 in the end, if `itself` is true.

```
([1] if one else []) + a + map(lambda x: n / x, reversed(a)) + ([n] if itself else [])
```

This is "clever" but inelegant.

```
if one:
    result = [1] + result
if itself:
    result = result + [n]
```

This is straight-forward but verbose.

Is it possible to implement optional one and itself in the output with the most concise yet readable code possible? Or maybe the whole idea should be done some other way - like the function `factors` can be written differently and still add optional 1 and itself?

Comment: The straight forward way isn't that verbose. I don't see a different way to do it the doesn't sacrifice readability.

Comment: You may think it is verbose but it is self explanatory and can easily be commented out without messing around with the core code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this?

```
[1] * one + result + [n] * itself
```

Comment: I was thinking `[1]*int(one) + result + [n]*int(itself)`, scrolled down and saw this beauty. Didn't know this could be done. +1

Comment: interesting... but please don't actually do this. "Programs must be written for people to read and only incidentally for machines to execute." This takes me way longer to read than the 4-liner.